# grep -w matches only the first occurrence of a pattern in a line

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I'm trying to understand why `grep -w` (version 3.1 of the GNU implementation) matches only the first occurrence of a certain pattern in a line.

Here's an example. I would expect that it would match `n1`, `n2` and `n3`, but it matches only the first one.

```
$ echo 'n1=1 n2=2 n3=3' | grep -ow "n[0-9]=*"
n1
```

Or if I tell it to match only `n2` or `n3`, again it matches the first one, and ignores `n3`.

```
$ echo 'n1=1 n2=2 n3=3' | grep -ow "n[23]=*" 
n2
```

What am I missing here? Is there any explanation for this behavior, or is it some sort of bug in grep?

The idea is to match either:

1. `n[0-9]` preceded and followed by a non-word character.
2. A substring that begin with `n[0-9]` followed by any number of `=` characters and ends with a non-word character.

So for instance, if the string is `n1=1 n2=== n3=3 n4== n5`, the expected result should be:

```
n1
n2===
n3
n4==
n5
```

**Clarification:** I know that the goal can be achieved by `grep -ow -e 'n[0-9]' -e "n[0-9]=*"`, but that's beside the point. The goal of the question is to understand how `grep` works.

#### Addition tests

If I add `n<num>=` to different places in the line (without a following word character after the equal sign), it will match those as well, but again it will ignore `n3=3`.

```
$ echo 'n1=1 n2= n3=3 n4=' | grep -ow "n[0-9]=*"
n1
n2=
n4=
```

Last thing that I've found is that if I add `-P` to interpret the pattern as a Perl-compatible regular expression, it doesn't seem to keep the `-w` description that says that the substring *"must be either at the end of the line or followed by a non-word constituent character"*, since it matches `n1=` even though it's followed by the character **1**, which is a word constituent character (*"letters, digits, and the underscore"*).

```
$ echo 'n1=1 n2= n3=3 n4=' | grep -owP "n[0-9]=*"
n1=
n2
n3=
n4
```

So it seems that `grep -wP` searches for a **word boundary** at the end of the substring rather than **a non-word constituent character**. It seems equivalent to:

```
$ echo 'n1=1 n2= n3=3 n4=' | grep -o "\bn[0-9]=*\b"
n1=
n2
n3=
n4
```

Comment: Your `grep -owP` example output is different from mine (mine is as I would expect)

Comment: I see ... yes .. sorry, I guess you're right....

Comment: Mmhh. Since `=` isn't a word-constituent character, I'm not sure how much sense it makes to have a pattern that can accept trailing `=`s while at the same time looking for whole word matches. I mean, if it's supposed to match a "word", the matching string would probably need to be such that it only contains characters valid in a "word".

Comment: @ilkkachu, the `-w, --word-regexp` section in the man pages of `grep` doesn't require that the substring must be comprised of word characters. It says nothing about the pattern itself. It only states what it should be preceded and followed with. So you can match a string that contains non-word characters, as long as it's preceded and followed with non-word characters (or beginning/end of the line).

Comment: And [the info page](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Matching-Control.html) specifically mentions that non-word characters *are* allowed: “Because the `-w` option can match a substring that does not begin and end with word constituents, it differs from surrounding a regular expression with ‘`\<`’ and ‘`\>`’.”

Comment: @aviro, It says it looks for "matches that form whole words". And ok, fine, if the man page says it accepts non-word characters, then it does. But it doesn't make any sense that a "whole word" could contain "non-word characters".

Answer (score 3):

Good catch. This seems indeed to be a bug in `grep`  (Tested with `GNU grep` 3.4 and 3.7):

```
grep -ow "n[0-9]=*"
grep -Eow "n[0-9]=*"
```

return only first match (or probably rather matches only the first one),
while ...

```
grep -Pow "n[0-9]=*"
```

... returns all matches as expected.

To report bugs for `GNU grep`, check [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Reporting-Bugs.html).

---

However, I cannot confirm your observation that *`-P` [...] doesn't seem to keep the `-w` description*, for me (GNU grep 3.4 and 3.7), the command outputs as expected:

```
$ echo 'n1=1 n2= n3=3 n4=' | grep -owP "n[0-9]=*"
n1
n2=
n3
n4=
```

Comment: Regarding the statement that "the pattern doesn't make too much sense", see my [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/692800/grep-w-matches-only-the-first-occurrence-of-a-pattern-in-a-line#comment1310244_692800) to my question. Also, your `sed` example is not relevant, since it's not equivalent to the `-w` flag in `grep`.

Comment: You're right, removed that bit ... Added a workaround though ;-)

Comment: Thanks, the Perl problem was probably fixed in a later version of `GNU grep`, I have version 3.1.

Comment: FWIW, `grep -o '\<n[0-9]=*\>'` or even `grep -wo '\<n[0-9]=*\>'` seems to work fine.

Comment: With the busybox or toybox implementations, `grep -ow "n[0-9]=*"` finds nothing. The ast-open implementation seems fine in that regard.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, grep -o '\<n[0-9]=*\>' doesn't do exactly what I was expecting; `=` signals the end of the word, so in case the string is `n1=`, (without any word characters following) it will only show `n1` instead of `n1=`.

Comment: @aviro, `\>` matches between a word and non-word characters (or the end of the subject). `=` is not a word characters, so `\>` can never match after it.  AFAIK, `-w` was added first to 2BSD grep is the late 70s along with `\<`, `\>`, and was just adding `\<` and `\>` around the regexp. GNU grep's `-w` is documented to behave differently, I don't know why they deviated from the BSD behaviour. But it goes to say that using `-w` to try and match things that don't begin or end with a word character is not portable.

Comment: (when I said ast-open works fine above, I meant it works as per the more usual meaning of `-w` like in the original BSD implementation, it outputs `n1`, `n2`, `n3`, not `n1=` `n2=` `n3=`). Note that in any case, none of `-w`, `-o`, `-P` are standard `grep` options.

Answer (score 2):

> So for instance, if the string is `n1=1 n2=== n3=3 n4== n5`, the
> expected result should be:
>
> ```
> n1
> n2===
> n3
> n4==
> n5
> ```
>
> Clarification: I know that the goal can be achieved by `grep -ow -e 'n[0-9]' -e "n[0-9]=*"`

Not so sure about that either:

```
u$ grep --version |head -1
grep (GNU grep) 2.27
u$ printf '%s\n' 'n1=1 n2=== n3=3 n4== n5' | grep -ow -e 'n[0-9]' -e "n[0-9]=*"
n1
n2===
n3
n4==
n5
```

vs.

```
a$ grep --version |head -1
grep (GNU grep) 3.4
a$ printf '%s\n' 'n1=1 n2=== n3=3 n4== n5' | grep -ow -e 'n[0-9]' -e "n[0-9]=*"
n1
n2===
n4==
n5
```

Note how `n3` is missing with the newer grep. That's on Ubuntu, the result s the same with 3.7.

And with Busybox, the answer is different again:

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'n1=1 n2=== n3=3 n4== n5' | busybox grep -ow -e 'n[0-9]' -e "n[0-9]=*"
n1
n2
n3
n4
n5
```

The BSD grep on my Mac also prints `n1`, `n2`... etc, but each one twice. For whatever reason.

Like [Stéphane said in the comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/692800/grep-w-matches-only-the-first-occurrence-of-a-pattern-in-a-line?noredirect=1#comment1310279_692806), using `-w` for that doesn't seem portable.

---

> The idea is to match either:
>
> - `n[0-9]` preceded and followed by a non-word character.
> - A substring that
>   begin with `n[0-9]` followed by any number of `=` characters and ends with
>   a non-word character.

This sounds to me like you want something like this in Perl (in this order, so that the one with `=` has priority):

```
/ n[0-9]=*(?=\W) | \bn[0-9]\b /x
```

E.g.

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'n1=1 n2=== n3=3 n4== n5' |
    perl -lne 'print $& while / n[0-9]=*(?=\W) | \bn[0-9]\b /xg'
n1
n2===
n3
n4==
n5
```

Except that I'm not exactly sure if that's what you want. If it's `n2===x` instead of `n2===`, the output is `n2==`, since the last `=` is used to fulfill the "ends with a non-word character" clause. (Or rather, "is followed by", since otherwise the match for `n1=1` should be `n1=` too. That would be `n1`, followed by zero `=`s, followed by a non-word character `=`.)

I think you could use the possessive quantifier `=*+` to avoid giving back any of the `=` signs for that, so:

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'n1=1 n2===X n3=3 n4== n5' |
    perl -lne 'print $& while / n[0-9]=*+(?=\W) | \bn[0-9]\b /xg'
n1
n2
n3
n4==
n5
```

In any case, I wonder if what you're trying to do would be better achieved by the simple logic of just splitting the string on whitespace, the substrings on the `=` signs and then looking at the individual values.